# Filter Helm buffers by mode in ibuffer

Tags: helm, major-mode, ibuffer

When I try to filter buffers by mode in `ibuffer`, I am not able to filter by major mode `helm-mode`.  For example,

```
 MR Name                 Size Mode
 -- ----                 ---- ----
 *  *helm apropos*        117 Helm             
 *  *helm projectile*    3633 Helm             
 *  *helm-package*        187 Helm
```

these three buffers say "Helm" in the mode column, but will only match `fundamental-mode` when filtering on major mode or derived mode.  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a bug. `helm.el` does not provide any major mode for helm buffers. So they are infact in `fundamental-mode`. However it does set the variable `mode-name` to `Helm` which is what you are seeing in the mode column. The `mode-name` variable is a buffer local variable that can contain a user friendly name for the buffer's major-mode and is/can be different from `major-mode`.

Check out the defun `helm-create-helm-buffer` for more details.

Note that `ibuffer` lets you mark all helm buffers by marking by mode regexp `% m`  followed by `Helm` at the prompt. The usual `* M` does not work though. If you want to create filter groups for helm, you can use the `ibuffer-filter-by-predicate` mapped to `/ e` and entering the following at the prompt.

```
(string-match "Helm" mode-name)
```

For instance, here is a working example of a saved filter group

[image]

and here is the resulting `ibuffer` window after `ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups`.

[image]

I can only guess why Helm does not have a dedicated major mode. Unlike buffers with major modes

- helm completion buffers are always disposable,
- do not need any special syntax map,
- font-lock is dependent upon the command invoked
- most importantly, keymap is active only for the active helm buffer

So there is no special reason for these buffers to have a dedicated major-mode. You can [ask the maintainer for his reasons though](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues). Maybe, the overhead of having a major-mode is not worth the trivial advantages it brings.

Comment: Unfortunately buffer marking functions do not allow me to create custom filter groups.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. So why is Helm changing `mode-name` without changing the mode?  Why not create an inherited mode from fundamental mode and invoke it from `helm-create-helm-buffer`?  Would there be some disadvantage to creating a helm mode vs faking it by overwriting `mode-name`?

Comment: Regarding why there is no dedicated major mode, I can only guess the intentions of the maintainer. There is nothing to be gained by defining a new major mode for helm completion buffers which are disposable. Mode-name is just the lighter for the modeline. For instance the scratch buffer has a `major mode` of `lisp-interaction-mode` while its `mode-name` is `Lisp Interaction`. `mode-name` is visible to the user, so a friendly string is often used.

Comment: @nispio I have edited the answer to show how you can filter helm buffers as well.